# what is the meaning of a colon in a list value in a yaml file, specifically :image of the stage build:image in a .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is the list value build:image just a name like build_image? Or does it have special usage in either the yaml file or the .gitlab-ci.yml file? If there isn't a special usage, what is the value of using name1:name2 instead of name1_name2?

The :image doesn't seem to be put into a variable. When I run this through the gitlab pipeline, the output is

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
Downloading artifacts
Running before_script and script
$ echo image is $image
image
is
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build:image
  - tag:image
  - deploy
build:
    stage: build:image
    script:
        - echo image is $image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything like this in the [GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/)

Where did you see this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

I ran the `.gitlab-ci.yml` you provided and it seems to work fine, apparently GitLab CI  doesn't treat the colon in any special way -- and I wouldn't expect it to, as there is no mention of it in the documentation.

Comment: This was simplified from an existing gitlab project at work. I was just double-checking to see if I was peering into arcane yaml dark arts.